# SQL: How to design a basic vote system schema

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, count

So far I have created these tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    email varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    username varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    user_password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    moderator boolean NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS post (
    post_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    post_data bytea NOT NULL,
    date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vote (
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    post_id integer NOT NULL,
    vote_value integer DEFAULT 1,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES post (post_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, post_id)
);
```

And I ultimately want to be able to get the username, post data, date, post id, and number of votes that particular post has in one query. So far I've been able to come up with the following which gets me each post's post id, post date, post data, and the user who submitted it, but I am struggling to also get total amount of votes for that particular post as another column.

```
SELECT users.username, post.post_data, post.date, post.post_id
FROM users 
INNER JOIN post ON post.user_id = users.user_id
ORDER BY post.date DESC
```

I am also open to a better overall database design if this approach seems flawed

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] When stuck explain what the queries you can write can do & how they relate to your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a correlated subquery that retrieves the count of votes from the `votes` table. I am unsure what the meaning of column `vote_value` is, but I assume that would be:

```
SELECT 
    u.username, 
    p.post_data, 
    p.date, 
    p.post_id,
    (SELECT SUM(vote_value) FROM votes v WHERE v.post_id = p.post_id) no_votes
FROM users u
INNER JOIN post p ON p.user_id = u.user_id
ORDER BY p.date DESC
```

Note the use of table aliases, that make the query easier to read and write.

Comment: ah I meant vote_value to be either an "upvote" or "downvote", that was what I was looking to do, thanks!